# What is the purpose of argmax in the PPO algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, gradient-descent, policy-gradients, proximal-policy-optimization

I'm kinda new to machine learning and still not too solid on math and particularly calculus. I'm currently trying to implement PPO algorithm as described in the spiningUp website : 
[image]

This line is giving me a hard time :

[image]

What does the $\operatorname{argmax}$ mean, in this context? They are also talking about updating the policy with a gradient ascent. So, is taking argmax with respect to $\theta$ the same as doing:

[image]

where $J$ is the min() function?

Answer (score 1):

In this case yes, $J$ is the big $\min$ expression and you apply Adam on that. But be careful because they say they do ascent, but automatic differentiation software usually minimizes given function so your $J$ would be $−\min(⋅)$.